# How to respawn enemy node after removing from parent?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add another enemy to the screen after it has been killed, but this doesn't seem to be working for me because I am not getting a new enemy. If you have any links that are similar to my problem I would appreciate that too! thanks ( let me know if you need to see more code I only have the function posted because I think thats the only relevant thing to show in this case)

```
 func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {

  print("Hit")
    
  run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("enemy-contact.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
  projectile.removeFromParent()
  monster.removeFromParent()

    //here is my code that should add the monster back after 2 sec
    monster.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)) {
        self.addChild(monster)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i just added self.run instead of monster and it worked nvm :|

Comment: Since  the answer was correct, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`monster` is no longer part of the scene, so it's not running anything.  You just need to flip the order around and run the action on the scene.